# Hello guys, is dimension reduction required for tensorflow?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, transfer-learning, vgg16

I am working on face emotion detection using FER2013 dataset using tensorflow and vgg16 model.
I am applying t-sne to my training dataset for dimensionality reduction.

My question is that "is dimensionality reduction required for the tensorflow ????

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensionality reduction is not related to TensorFlow's CNN training:

- Dimensionality reduction is for unsupervised data clustering and classification. Not sure if you will cluster expressions clearly because they are not the most remarkable points on faces.
- CNN training consists of supervised training where you indicate the expressions to recognize. For instance, all pictures flagged with "happiness" will be trained to detect happy strokes of happiness (around the eyes, smile, etc.).

I would recommend Dimensionality Reduction using the CNN training's output, i.e. the softmax activations.

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/view-network-behavior-using-tsne.html